# How to configure sales emails for Magento 1.x.

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to setup sales emails.
like, When customer purchase an order or make payment or abandoned checkout, website sends me an email.

How to configure it ?
our website is : https://thevcollection.com

Thanks

Comment: Hello @Shubham Raj, As a advice you first study basics, you ask one of the basics for Magento, study well using following link http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/frontmatter/contents.html and don't share your website URL and other vital source for security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

These links will help you. Please check

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ee/user_guide/order-processing/sales-email-setup.html

https://stuntcoders.com/magento-tutorials/magento-orders/managing-sales-emails/

Comment: Dear Kalyan Chakravarthi V,
I have already tried these steps but these are not working.
I and customer both are not receiving any email after placing an order or even after creating an account on website.

There are any Mail server related changes to put in the code like email address, mail server port number or mail server information?

Or any ? Please ASAP

Comment: Ok all admin related configuration is set right ? Are you using any different mail server ?

Comment: Dear V, Yes all configuration are correct.
Yes, our domain is from Godaddy and website hosted on another server and our mail hosting is from Zoho. Please advice if you have, Thousands like in advance.

Comment: You can install this extension and provide SMTP configuration through that, this will help you. In order to get SMTP configuraiton please check with the ZOHO team, they will help you to provide all the details required for the extension.

Lnik: http://www.aschroder.com/product/smtppro-magento-smtp-email/

Comment: Thanks for now, But there are any issues of 'Cron Job'? because we have installed 'Cron'.  and it is showing an error 'No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly. (See Instructions)' in System > Scheduler > Job Configuration

When i click on "See instruction" it is showing these options following checkbox, What i need to do check ?- 

1)Run scheduler_cron.sh instead cron.sh (recommended)

2)Run every minute (recommended)

3)Check maintenance mode (recommended)

4)Use multiple cron groups (example)

5)Use watchdog

6)Include email address for output messages

Comment: if heartbeat task is not found means cron is not set. But it is difficult to say without checking the cron configuration in your server and doing some tests.

Comment: ok! After the cron job error. can i install and configure this extension ??. Link: aschroder.com/product/smtppro-magento-smtp-email

Comment: Yes, you can install the suggested extension and configure required details.